# Shortcuts for WebStorm and IntelliJ not showing

Tags: 20.04, launcher, shortcuts

I have tried to install `.desktop` files. I'm absolutely baffled that I still cannot simply right-click an open application and say "Add Shortcut". This is simply not working for everything.

However, these are my paths to IntelliJ and WebStorm

```
/opt/idea-IU-203.6682.168/bin
/opt/WebStorm-203.6682.155/bin
```

And here are the files I created under `/usr/share/applications`:

**intellij.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=IntelliJ
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/opt/idea-IU-203.6682.168/bin/idea.sh
Icon=/opt/idea-IU-203.6682.168/bin/idea.png
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.24
```

**webstorm.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WebStorm
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/WebStorm-203.6682.155/bin/webstorm.png
Exec=/opt/WebStorm-203.6682.155/bin/webstorm.sh
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.24
```

I already tried to run `desktop-file-install` on them and restarted the machine but the shortcuts are not showing up.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

No idea why the above is not working but simply start your JetBrains product and go to `Tools -> Create Desktop Entry..`

I know.

It's not creating a Desktop Entry but a shortcut/favorite in the menu bar, I mean task bar.. sorry, I mean `Dock`.